# How to get document ids from collection in Watson Discovery

Tags: ibm-watson, watson, watson-discovery

Is there any way to list metadata(like id, filename etc.) about documents which belong to certain collection of Watson Discovery?

There are some API methods which need document id (like "delete document" for example), so obviously there should be a way to get this id. 
However I was not able to find how to do it (neither via UI nor via API).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, the answer was obvious - to query the collection via Discovery Query Language.

The query `*.*` will list all the documents in the collection.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the query language to retrieve information about documents in a collection. At the time of this posting, using the following query should return 10 documents with all available metadata (replacing the appropriate values in {} with your collection-specific details):

```
curl -u "{username}:{password}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/{environment_id}/collections/{collection_id}/query?count=10&return=extracted_metadata&version=2017-01-01"
```

Documentation: https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/discovery-v1#!/Queries/query